# Google Map Zoom Setting on V3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am working on Google Map V3. I am trying to set the zoom level to occupy all markers. The code is below

```
      <script>
  var Duabi = new google.maps.LatLng(25.232274,55.332642);
  var marker;
  var map;

   var locations = [
   ['Al Ain Rotana',24.2187077269409,55.7486816157711,"<a href='/ems/public/Company/Manage/view/est_id/MjYxNA==' target='_blank'>View Details<\/a>"],['Al Bustan Rotana',25.2483086562942,55.3453971796322,"<a href='/ems/public/Company/Manage/view/est_id/MTM3Nw==' target='_blank'>View Details<\/a>"],['Al Ghurair Arjaan by Rotana',25.2695672065064,55.3171133437058,"<a href='/ems/public/Company/Manage/view/est_id/MTM5NTkw' target='_blank'>View Details<\/a>"],['Al Ghurair Rayhaan By Rotana',25.26751,55.31715,"<a href='/ems/public/Company/Manage/view/est_id/MTI5Njk2' target='_blank'>View Details<\/a>"],['Al Ghurair Rayhaan By Rotana',25.2689526605375,55.3169359915134,"<a href='/ems/public/Company/Manage/view/est_id/MTI5Njk1' target='_blank'>View Details<\/a>"],['Al Maha Arjaan By Rotana',24.4921202648678,54.3674452492895,"<a href='/ems/public/Company/Manage/view/est_id/NzQwNQ==' target='_blank'>View Details<\/a>"],['Al Murooj Rotana',25.2027734837341,55.2778133352192,"<a href='/ems/public/Company/Manage/view/est_id/MTMyNDA=' target='_blank'>View Details<\/a>"],['Al Rawda Arjaan By Rotana',24.4691980739652,54.3723774450805,"<a href='/ems/public/Company/Manage/view/est_id/MjQzOQ==' target='_blank'>View Details<\/a>"],['Amwaj Rotana Jumeirah Beach Residence',25.0734792101092,55.1308173703686,"<a href='/ems/public/Company/Manage/view/est_id/NjEzNDQ=' target='_blank'>View Details<\/a>"],['Arjaan By Rotana',25.09568,55.15381,"<a href='/ems/public/Company/Manage/view/est_id/NjI0NDc=' target='_blank'>View Details<\/a>"],['Beach Rotana Abu Dhabi',24.4945924700841,54.3841634196444,"<a href='/ems/public/Company/Manage/view/est_id/MjE3MA==' target='_blank'>View Details<\/a>"],['BurJuman Arjaan By Rotana',25.2518237482319,55.3014216739748,"<a href='/ems/public/Company/Manage/view/est_id/MzE2MDc=' target='_blank'>View Details<\/a>"],['Capital Centre Arjaan By Rotana',24.41996,54.44185,"<a href='/ems/public/Company/Manage/view/est_id/MTI1NTkx' target='_blank'>View Details<\/a>"],['Capital Centre Rotana',24.41982,54.44219,"<a href='/ems/public/Company/Manage/view/est_id/NjY2ODI=' target='_blank'>View Details<\/a>"],['Fujairah Rotana Resort & Spa - Al Aqah Beach',25.50868,56.36336,"<a href='/ems/public/Company/Manage/view/est_id/NDMxNA==' target='_blank'>View Details<\/a>"],['Grand Rotana',24.2187077269409,55.7486816157711,"<a href='/ems/public/Company/Manage/view/est_id/MTUxNTk=' target='_blank'>View Details<\/a>"],['Hala Arjaan By Rotana',24.50123,54.37793,"<a href='/ems/public/Company/Manage/view/est_id/NjUwOTU=' target='_blank'>View Details<\/a>"],['Hili Rayhaan By Rotana',24.27384,55.77954,"<a href='/ems/public/Company/Manage/view/est_id/NjYzMjA=' target='_blank'>View Details<\/a>"],['Hili Reyhaan by Rotana',24.27357,55.77900,"<a href='/ems/public/Company/Manage/view/est_id/MTQxNTM1' target='_blank'>View Details<\/a>"],['International Rotana Inn',24.4974871914531,54.373612287925,"<a href='/ems/public/Company/Manage/view/est_id/MjMzMQ==' target='_blank'>View Details<\/a>"],['Jumeira Rotana',25.2373282998585,55.274198112447,"<a href='/ems/public/Company/Manage/view/est_id/MjYwOA==' target='_blank'>View Details<\/a>"],['Khalidiya Palace Rayhaan By Rotana',24.45975,54.31256,"<a href='/ems/public/Company/Manage/view/est_id/NjYzMTU=' target='_blank'>View Details<\/a>"],['Marina Mall Arjaan by Rotana',24.4756970326267,54.3218642298077,"<a href='/ems/public/Company/Manage/view/est_id/NjY2ODk=' target='_blank'>View Details<\/a>"],['Media Rotana',25.0998417925132,55.179632179501,"<a href='/ems/public/Company/Manage/view/est_id/NjEzNDY=' target='_blank'>View Details<\/a>"],['Media Rotana events and promotions',25.0998417925132,55.179632179501,"<a href='/ems/public/Company/Manage/view/est_id/MTI4MTI5' target='_blank'>View Details<\/a>"],['Mina Al Arab Rotana Resort',25.71865,55.84713,"<a href='/ems/public/Company/Manage/view/est_id/NjY2OTc=' target='_blank'>View Details<\/a>"],['Nour Arjaan By Rotana',25.12265,56.32716,"<a href='/ems/public/Company/Manage/view/est_id/MTI3Mjg5' target='_blank'>View Details<\/a>"],['Park Arjaan By Rotana',24.42406,54.47348,"<a href='/ems/public/Company/Manage/view/est_id/NjUwOTQ=' target='_blank'>View Details<\/a>"],['Park Rotana Abu Dhabi',24.42361,54.47384,"<a href='/ems/public/Company/Manage/view/est_id/NjUwOTI=' target='_blank'>View Details<\/a>"],['Rihab Rotana Dubai',25.2538952503536,55.3357809787836,"<a href='/ems/public/Company/Manage/view/est_id/ODI1Ng==' target='_blank'>View Details<\/a>"],['Rimal Rotana',25.2643012871287,55.3268515021216,"<a href='/ems/public/Company/Manage/view/est_id/Nzk5MA==' target='_blank'>View Details<\/a>"],['Rose Rayhaan By Rotana',25.21180624263,55.2765817489046,"<a href='/ems/public/Company/Manage/view/est_id/NjEzNDc=' target='_blank'>View Details<\/a>"],['Rotana Beach Club',24.4945924700841,54.3841634196444,"<a href='/ems/public/Company/Manage/view/est_id/Nzg3MA==' target='_blank'>View Details<\/a>"],['Rotana Jet',24.42769,54.45760,"<a href='/ems/public/Company/Manage/view/est_id/MTM3ODcy' target='_blank'>View Details<\/a>"],['Rotana Jet',24.42769,54.45760,"<a href='/ems/public/Company/Manage/view/est_id/MTM3Mjk0' target='_blank'>View Details<\/a>"],['Rotana Junior Golf League',24.4433025744182,54.3767662975431,"<a href='/ems/public/Company/Manage/view/est_id/NzY5MA==' target='_blank'>View Details<\/a>"],['Rotana Mall',24.4702749578096,54.3424631693569,"<a href='/ems/public/Company/Manage/view/est_id/MzMzOQ==' target='_blank'>View Details<\/a>"],['Rotana Pharmacy',25.07323,55.13135,"<a href='/ems/public/Company/Manage/view/est_id/MTM1Mjc5' target='_blank'>View Details<\/a>"],['Saadiyat Rotana Resort & Spa',24.54516,54.43398,"<a href='/ems/public/Company/Manage/view/est_id/NjUwOTY=' target='_blank'>View Details<\/a>"],['Sharjah Rotana',25.36242,55.39146,"<a href='/ems/public/Company/Manage/view/est_id/NDY4MQ==' target='_blank'>View Details<\/a>"],['The Cove Rotana Resort',25.73667,55.88719,"<a href='/ems/public/Company/Manage/view/est_id/NjM5NDk=' target='_blank'>View Details<\/a>"],['Towers Rotana',25.21300,55.27517,"<a href='/ems/public/Company/Manage/view/est_id/NTE5OA==' target='_blank'>View Details<\/a>"],['Villa Rotana',25.1945554780764,55.2614536265911,"<a href='/ems/public/Company/Manage/view/est_id/NjA4MTQ=' target='_blank'>View Details<\/a>"],['Yas Island Rotana',24.46628,54.59933,"<a href='/ems/public/Company/Manage/view/est_id/NjU0MjM=' target='_blank'>View Details<\/a>"],['Zen The Spa At Rotana',24.4945924700841,54.3841634196444,"<a href='/ems/public/Company/Manage/view/est_id/NjMzMDY=' target='_blank'>View Details<\/a>"],      ];


  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 10,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: Duabi
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
            mapOptions);

   var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

   var marker, i;
   var mybounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

   var latlng=new Array(); 
   var latlng = [
                 new google.maps.LatLng(24.2187077269409, 55.7486816157711),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(25.2483086562942, 55.3453971796322),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(25.2695672065064, 55.3171133437058),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(25.26751, 55.31715),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(25.2689526605375, 55.3169359915134),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(24.4921202648678, 54.3674452492895),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(25.2027734837341, 55.2778133352192),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(24.4691980739652, 54.3723774450805),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(25.0734792101092, 55.1308173703686),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(25.09568, 55.15381),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(24.4945924700841, 54.3841634196444),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(25.2518237482319, 55.3014216739748),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(24.41996, 54.44185),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(24.41982, 54.44219),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(25.50868, 56.36336),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(24.2187077269409, 55.7486816157711),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(24.50123, 54.37793),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(24.27384, 55.77954),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(24.27357, 55.77900),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(24.4974871914531, 54.373612287925),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(25.2373282998585, 55.274198112447),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(24.45975, 54.31256),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(24.4756970326267, 54.3218642298077),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(25.0998417925132, 55.179632179501),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(25.0998417925132, 55.179632179501),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(25.71865, 55.84713),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(25.12265, 56.32716),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(24.42406, 54.47348),
                        ];

   //alert(JSON.stringify(latlng));
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  



  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map,
    title: locations[i][0]
  });
  alert(latlng[i]);
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent('<b>'+locations[i][0]+'</b></br>'+locations[i][3]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);

     mybounds.extend(latlng[i]);
    }
  })(marker, i));


  }
 map.fitBounds(mybounds);

  }
  </script>
```

### No Listing Available

But it is not zooming to fit the markers. The markers are loading from database to the script. and I need to set its center point on map and have to occupy all markers in the map. Please let me know where I missed.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are extending the bounds inside the listener. Try moving

```
mybounds.extend(latlng[i]);
```

outside the listener

```
mybounds.extend(latlng[i]);
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
        infowindow.setContent('<b>'+locations[i][0]+'</b></br>'+locations[i][3]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);

    }
})(marker, i));
```

on the other hand, your latlng array doesn't contain as many locations as your location array, so you won't be fitting all the locations in the map, only the latlng.